# Строка по z-функции (golang)

Tags: алгоритм, golang

Ссылка на задачу https://codeforces.com/edu/course/2/lesson/3/2/practice/contest/272261/problem/C
Вкратце нужно из чисел z-функции получить валидную строку или в случаи если это невозможно вернуть !, можете подсказать в чем я напортачил или подсказку.

```
func zToStr(slc []int) string {
    k := len(slc)
    res := make([]string, k)
    res[0] = "a"

    curSym := 'b'
    notThis := 0
    last := 0

    for i := 1; i < k; i++ {
        z := slc[i]
        if z > k-i {
            return "!"
        }
        if z > 0 {
            for j := int(math.Max(float64(last-i), 0)); j < z; j++ {
                res[i+j] = res[j]
                last = i + j
            }
            notThis = z
        } else {
            if last >= i {
                continue
            }
            if res[notThis] == string(curSym) {
                curSym = (curSym+1-'a')%26 + 'a'
            }
            res[i] = string(curSym)
            curSym = (curSym+1-'a')%26 + 'a'
            if curSym == 'a' {
                curSym = 'b'
            }
            last = i
        }
    }
    str := strings.Join(res, "")
    for i, val := range zFunc(str) {
        if val != slc[i] {
            return "!"
        }
    }

    return str
}
```

Comment: Что-то мне кажется, что такую задачу уже решали - однако поиском не нашёл

Comment: вот и я ее не нашел

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот переписанный вариант

```
func z2s(z []int) string {
    s := ""
    prefixLength := 0
    j := 0
    newCharacter := 'a'
    for i := 0; i < len(z); i++ {
        if z[i] > len(z)-i {
            return "!"
        }
        if z[i] == 0 && prefixLength == 0 {
            if newCharacter <= 'z' {
                s += string(newCharacter)
                newCharacter++
            } else {
                s += string(newCharacter - 1)
            }
        }
        if z[i] > prefixLength {
            prefixLength = z[i]
            j = 0
        }
        if prefixLength > 0 {
            s += string(s[j])
            j++
            prefixLength--
        }
    }
    z1 := zFunc(s)
    for i := 0; i < len(z); i++ {
        if z1[i] != z[i] {
            return "!"
        }
    }
    return s
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Из закромов на Python. Функция z->str, вероятно, [взята отсюда](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=Z-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.9F.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D1.81.D1.82.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.BA.D0.B8_.D0.BF.D0.BE_Z-.D1.84.D1.83.D0.BD.D0.BA.D1.86.D0.B8.D0.B8), длину алфавита не учитывает.

P.S. А вот это вот безобразие обязательно? `int(math.Max(float64(...`

```
def z_function(s):
    n = len(s)
    z = [0]*n
    l = 0
    r = 0
    for i in range(1, n):
        if (i <= r):
            z[i] = min (r-i+1, z[i-l])
        while (i+z[i] < n) and (s[z[i]] == s[i+z[i]]):
            z[i] += 1
        if (i+z[i]-1 > r):
            l = i
            r = i+z[i]-1
    return z

def z2s(z):
    s = ""
    prefpos = 0
    preflen = 0
    char = "a"
    for x in z:
        if x == 0 and preflen == 0:
            s += char
            char = chr(ord(char)+1)
        if preflen < x:
            preflen = x
            prefpos = 0
        if preflen:
            preflen -= 1
            s += s[prefpos]
            prefpos += 1
    return s

def compare_strs(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) != len(s2):
        return False
    dic1 = dict()
    dic2 = dict()
    for a, b in zip(s1, s2):
        if dic1.setdefault(a, b) != b or dic2.setdefault(b, a) != a:
            return False
    return True


s = "ababcaba"
s = "cacafcac"
print(s)
z = z_function(s)
print(z)
ss = z2s(z)
print(ss)
print("Nice" if compare_strs(s, ss) else "Bad...")
```

Comment: спасибо за ссылку
по поводу math.Max, он принимает только float64, а автоприведения нет, либо я чего-то не знаю